# How can I wait for additional client input on client handler ? Socket

Tags: java, sockets, client, serversocket

On first try everything works properly and changes values as it should, but when loop is finished and client restarts and one should be able to make new inputs, Connection thread becomes asynchronized with client inputs and request string is being assigned to sth else.

As the client starts there should be inputs for name and hours/date but after complete reservation around line 97 in Connection, input and output is wrong they get mismatched. I think it is caused by asking for additional input to confirm reservation. or I incorrectly loop /return to begining.
This is Client Handler class

```
public class Connection extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
private Data Ledger;
private Reservation that_r;
private Integer month;
private Integer day;
private Integer hour;

public Connection(Socket socket, Data Ledger) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.Ledger = Ledger;
}
@Override
synchronized public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);




        while(true) {
            String request = in.readLine();
            if(request.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }

            do{
                Boolean  completion = Boolean.FALSE;

                System.out.println("Received client input: " + request);
                out.println("Write Day + Hour you want to reserve");


                String R_name =  in.readLine();
                System.out.println("name " + R_name);
                String R_month =  in.readLine();
                System.out.println("month "+R_month);
                String R_day =  in.readLine();
                System.out.println("day "+R_day);
                String R_hour =  in.readLine();
                System.out.println("hour "+R_hour);

                out.println("Checking for existing reservation");

                try{this.month = Integer.parseInt(R_month);}
                catch (Exception e){System.out.println("sth wrong"+e.getMessage());out.println("Wrong number"); }
                try{this.day = Integer.parseInt(R_day);}
                catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("sth wrong "+e.getMessage());out.println("Wrong number"); }
                try{this.hour = Integer.parseInt(R_hour);}
                catch (Exception e){System.out.println("sth wrong "+e.getMessage());out.println("Wrong number");}

                try {
                    if (Ledger.findReservation(month, day, hour).getReserved()){
                        System.out.println(Ledger.reservations);
                        out.println("Currently being reserved sorry");
                        out.println("press Enter");
                        out.println("END");
                        return;
                    }
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    this.that_r = new Reservation(R_name,month,day,hour,true);
                    Ledger.reservations.add(that_r);
                    out.println("Checking if available");
                    try {if (Ledger.findDay(month, day).aval(hour)){
                        out.println("Can be reserved, RESERVE Y/N");
                        completion = true;
                        out.println("END");
                      }else{
                        out.println("Sorry it is not available but you know that already as you can see all free termines");
                        out.println("END");
                        return;
                      }
                    }catch (NullPointerException f){
                        out.println("Day you want to reserve is not here");
                    }
                }
                if (completion){
                    String answer = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(answer);
                    if (answer.equals("y")) {
                        Ledger.findDay(month,day).changeaval(hour,Boolean.FALSE);
                        //out.println("END");


                    }
                    if (answer.equals("n")) {
                        Ledger.reservations.remove(that_r);
                    }
                    if (answer.equals("")){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }while (request.equals("r"));

            if (request.equals("show")){
                out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2019,1,5,23,55));
                out.println("END");
                out.flush();

            }
            }

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
            for (Day x: Ledger.ledger){
                System.out.println(x.getDay()+" / "+ x.getMonth());
                System.out.println(x.getSchedule());
            }

            for (Reservation x: Ledger.reservations){
                System.out.println(x.getDay()+" / "+ x.getMonth());
                System.out.println(x.getName()+" "+ x.getHour());
            }

        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
}
```

And then there is Client side

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000)) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        do {
            System.out.println("r for reserving ");
            System.out.println("show for showing reservations");

            input = scanner.nextLine();
            out.println(input);
            out.flush();

            if (input.equals("r")) {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("name");
                String new_name = scanner.nextLine();
                out.println(new_name);

                System.out.println("month");
                String new_month = scanner.nextLine();
                out.println(new_month);

                System.out.println("day");
                String new_day = scanner.nextLine();
                out.println(new_day);

                System.out.println("hour");
                String new_hour= scanner.nextLine();
                out.println(new_hour);

                System.out.println("wait");

                listen(in);

                String answer = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("answered " + answer);
                out.println(answer);
            }
        } while (!input.equals("exit"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Client Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void listen(BufferedReader in) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            String p = in.readLine();
            if (p.equals("END")) {
                break;
            }else{System.out.println(p);}

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}
}
```

I want to client make new inputs after failed reservation or completed reservation or after some other process so that connection- client handler see that and also assigns inputs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending several individual pieces of information, I would recommend encapsulating all the reservation info and avoid the headache that comes with preserving the order should multiple clients connect and send their reservations. E.g. Reservation reservation1 = new Reservation(name, month, hour). Then simply send it all in one chunk:  out.write(reservation1.getBytes())

Comment: So just sending object instead of strings ?

Comment: Exactly. Construct the Reservation object on the client side, serialize it, receive it on the server side, deserialize it, process the reservation object